# Networks In Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Stopped Working Since Last Update

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet

The wifi stopped working, so I plugged in a ethernet cable, and `lshw -C network` shows both adapters as unclaimed. I have tried a few things suggestions found google that didn't work, before trying to reinstall Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 LTS.

I'm writing this from the same computer now logged into windows, so there's nothing wrong with the hardware, both wifi and ethernet are shown in windows.

The clean install still did not have any network connection on the first boot (or during install). I'm on the 2nd boot attempt and I now HAVE wifi, but the ethernet is still unclaimed.

I have an Asus TUF 550 motherboard with wifi. It seems a few people have had this [issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/599844/network-cable-not-working-in-ubuntu-network-unclaimed).

This has happened a few times to me since installing Ubuntu 20.04 on this desktop, but not with my dell inspiron 2016.

```
sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for bryan: 
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
       logical name: wlp5s0
       version: 1a
       serial: 14:f6:d8:7f:b8:45
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.8.0-43-generic firmware=55.d9698065.0 cc-a0-55.ucode latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:34 memory:fc600000-fc603fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
       version: 04
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:fc500000-fc50ffff memory:fc510000-fc513fff
```

Comment: There is no information to suggest anything. There is no "Ubuntu 20" release. I think "switching back to Windows" is a good solution if all works there.

Comment: what information would you like? I don't exactly have access to terminal and the internet as the same time

Comment: We don't know what sort of Ethernet and Wi-Fi hardware you have. You can connect to the internet using your phone. Also make sure Windows Fast Strtup feature is disabled.

Comment: Did networking work when you re-installed Ubuntu in a Live session?

Comment: Now after the second login since reinstall the wifi works. I'm logged in now. But the ethernet does not. I'll edit the post to show the output

Comment: You need a driver for RTL8125. It isn't supported by the 5.8 kernel.

Comment: For a dual boot with Windows you need to have Fast Sturtup disabled for Intel wireless adapters.

Comment: I see this problem has been going on for 8 months now. https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/realtek-rtl8125-2-5gbe-ethernet-not-working-on-amd-b550-mobo/22469 This update broke my pc, and I've been trying to fix it all day. Why?

Comment: Your device is not supported by the kernel. If you install a driver without dkms, it will be broken after each kernel update. Another option is to install a newer kenel and stick to it for a while.

Comment: what is dkms? If I use auto update, don't I have the most current kernel?

Comment: You can easily find what dkms is. You won't get a kernel that natively supports your Ethernet device by normal updates till 20.04.3.

Answer (score 0):

Networking should be working during the Live session, did it work? If it worked something happened during the installation process. Try some of the Ubuntu flavors instead of clean Ubuntu. If only WiFi is not working, when you plug the cable and you have internet it might be just missing driver. Look for a proprietary one in your Drivers Manager. One of my laptops works only with a proprietary driver for the Wifi, otherwise it gets limited connection or simply disconnects...